# How to read the object name from memory?

Tags: python, class, object, memory, instance

I wrote a simple class code like below.

```
class Fridge:

def __init__(self):
    self.isOpened = False
    self.foods = []

def open(self):
    self.isOpened = True

def put(self, thing):
    if self.isOpened:
        self.foods.append(thing)

def close(self):
    self.isOpened = False

class Food:
    pass
```

And then import the module...

```
import class_practice as fridge

f = fridge.Fridge()
apple = fridge.Food()
elephant = fridge.Food()

f.open()
f.put(apple)
f.put(elephant)

print(f.foods)
```

The print output is

```
[<class_practice.Food object at 0x7fe761fce5f8>, <class_practice.Food object at 0x7fe761fce710>]
```

In this case, if I want to print out `f.foods` as the object name of `[apple, elephant]`,

how could I do?

**##Revised##**

I want to extract data from

```
[<class_practice.Food object at 0x7fe761fce5f8>, <class_practice.Food object at 0x7fe761fce710>]
```

as the form of ['apple', 'elephant'].

It is like,

```
a = 'hello'
b = id(a)
print(ctypes.cast(b, ctypes.py_object).value)
```

And then, the result is 'hello'

Answer (score 1):

Store the value in a instance attribute, and return it from the `__repr__` dunder method:

```
class Food:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
     
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.value
```

You will need to pass the value when constructing `Food`:

```
apple = fridge.Food("apple")
elephant = fridge.Food("elephant")
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try the following:

```
class Fridge:

    def __init__(self):
        self.isOpened = False
        self.foods = []

    def open(self):
        self.isOpened = True

    def put(self, thing):
        if self.isOpened:
            self.foods.append(thing)

    def close(self):
        self.isOpened = False

class Food:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
     
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.value

import class_practice as fridge
f = fridge.Fridge()
f.open()
f.put(fridge.Food('apple'))
f.put(fridge.Food('elephant'))
print(f.foods)
```

Output:

```
[apple, elephant]
```

Comment: Thank for your reply, 
Is there a way to get the stored data from 0x7fe761fce5f8?